# How can I interact with rather long python scripts?

Tags: python, python-idle

I love the IDLE. However, sometimes I have 100-200 line scripts and I want to sort of interactively debug/play with say, functions defined in `foo.py` instead of just calling `python foo.py`. Is there a way I can trigger IDLE in the context of my `foo.py`?

Comment: "debug/play" is not testing.  Please change the title to remove "testing".  You're not testing if you don't have a fixed test script with expected results that could be automated.

Comment: @mizipzor - sure, although a good percentage of my questions are still unanswered, or I haven't had the time to implement the answers yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert this line into the script:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Which will start the [python debugger](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) which lets you step through the script interactively, checking variables and such as you go.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking about how to enable debugging in Idle?

In the `Python Shell` window, choose *Debugger* from the *Debug* menu, then open `foo.py` and use the *Run Model* command. A *Debug Control* window opens, allowing you to step through the execution of foo.py; when execution is over, the prompt is still available for you to manually call functions, interact with objects or otherwise tinker with your application (and you will be still debugging the script).